# Can I manipulate Web pages from Xcode UI Testing?

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I have my test cases written in Swift3 UI Testing in Xcode, my test cases run in an iOS application in simulator. One of our functionalities is bring assets into our app from dropbox, whenever we tap on dropbox icon (from our app) the dropbox web site opens to allow the user to LogIn. my question is, is there any way to use swift code that can automate the logIn on the web site? I would like to automate all that process.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to use XCTest UI tests to test anything other than an application you created.

The tests are only able to interact with a single application, and the bundle ID must match the bundle ID in the Info.plist for the UI tests.